# In Unity Hub, why can't I see a remote project

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've just spent the last 2h trying to find information about why I can't see a cloud project when clicking on "Add remote project" in "Unity Hub".

I've added the correct email to the project in Unity.

```
https://cloud.unity.com/home/organizations/[Organisation Number]/projects/[Project UID]/members
```

[image: Unity Hub not displaying remote projects even if added to correct organization]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was not very well documented from Unity. You have to add the user to "DevOps" in "Unity Cloud".

Here are a few links for reference

DevOps:

```
https://cloud.unity.com/home/organizations/[Your Organisation Number]/devops/get-started
```

DevOps Seats:

```
https://cloud.unity.com/home/organizations/[Your Organisation Number]/plastic-scm/organizations/[Your Project Name]/seats
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also not working for me, and I'm the project owner, I have the DEVOPS with a repo and everything supposedly up and running following the instructions. On the browser it shows everything, but I'm at the same position of the initial post.

Comment: This feels more like a comment (to the original question) than an answer/solution.